# Form / template help

Tags: form, template

Im looking for advice/help in creating a form in sharepoint 2010.

I believe a form is the easiest way to do it, but my goal is to replicate some document templates I have on word. These templates have sections and descriptions that can not be modified by the user (like the tittles), and the form space between sections or tittles, should be resizable depending on the amount of text, and should be able to handle images in the same field.

Whats the best way to achieve this on sharepoint? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sticking with Word documents *may* be the right approach, especially since you want to mix text and images in fields.

Using the Documrnt Information Panel (DIP) and promoted column data, you can bring the data and document into a SharePoint library for other purposes.

You haven't said what your real goals are, so those are my first suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply, and I apologize I was not clear explaining what my goal is.
I currently have a few templates on word that users fill during different phases on projects. The goal is to have these templates online. 
I initially thought a form would be the best way to go, but now I am leaning more towards a WIKI. I just need to find out if there is a way to create a template in a wiki page. Or is there a better way to do this? 
Thanks for all the help

Comment: You've just restated what you originally said. Why do you want the forms online? What are you trying to accomplish? A Wiki is meant for many users to edit collaboratively, so I don't see how that could be the right answer.